# How to select (this) image when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have an image that i want to duplicate to another position when clicked. And instead of putting the source directly, i want to select that particular clicked image as i have multiple images.

Also I am struggling to append the text from the clicked object (title, rating etc etc).
Question marks in my JS code highlight what i am having difficulties with.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Renay/km25vo7m/) to make sense of what i'm trying to describe. Sorry about the CSS.

Still sort of new to creating larger sites/apps and using objects so any help or step in the right direction is really appreciated. 
If i am going about it the wrong way please let me know.

HTML:

```
<header>
            <h1> Playstation 4 Games </h1>
</header>
        <div id = 'selectionContainer'> </div>
     <div id = 'gamesContainer'> 
            <ul> 
                <li> <img src='http://s18.postimg.org/dyrfzmbsp/callofdutyadvancedwarfareboxart1.jpg' class='gameCover' id='codImage'> </li>
                <li> <img src='http://s1.postimg.org/64gqkaoqn/13741695334_e2f461ca7a.jpg' class='gameCover' id='theLastOfUsImage'> </li>
                <li> <img src='http://s13.postimg.org/ovz0ll0kn/fifa_15_cover_ps4.jpg' class='gameCover' id='fifaImage'> </li>
                <li> <img src='http://s15.postimg.org/agb7y3qej/ass_creed_ps4_box_70305_1405370733_1280_1280_jp.jpg' class='gameCover'> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function game(theTitle, theGenre, theIGNRating, theDescription) {
    this.gameTitle = theTitle;
    this.genre = theGenre;
    this.rating = theIGNRating;
    this.gameDescription = theDescription;

    this.showGame = function() {
    return  'Title: ' + this.gameTitle + 'Genre: ' + this.genre + 'IGN Rating: ' + this.rating + 'Description: ' + this.gameDescription;

    }
}

var callOfDuty = new game('Call of Duty Advanced Warefare', 'First Person Shooter', '9.1/10', 'Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare envisions the powerful battlegrounds of the future, where both technology and tactic have evolved to usher in a new era of combat for the franchise.');

var theLastOfUs = new game('The Last Of Us Remastered', 'Action', '10/10', 'Survive an apocalypse on Earth in The Last of Us. Here, you will find abandoned cities reclaimed by nature. Here is a population decimated by a modern plague. Here, there are only survivors killing each other for food, weapons, or whatever they can get their hands on. Here, you find no hope.')

var fifa15 = new game('FIFA 15', 'Sports', '8.3', 'FIFA 15 brings football to life in stunning detail so fans can experience the emotion of the sport like never before. ')

var assasinsCreed = new game('Assassins Creed Unity', 'Action', '7.8', 'Set in a once-magnificent Paris, Assassin’s Creed Unity plunges into the terror of the 1789 French Revolution and features the most dense and immersive Assassin’s Creed city ever created. Through the streets of Paris, the starving inhabitants are set to take up arms for freedom and equality. In this time of chaos and brutality, a young man named Arno, wounded by the loss of those he loved, sets on a deadly path of redemption.')

// Clicking a game cover brings it up to the main container

$('.gameCover').click(function() {
    var sourceImage = document.createElement('img');
        sourceImage.className = 'gameCoverFocus';
        //How can you select the image that is clicked?
        // This.img????????????? 
        sourceImage.src = '??????';
    var theDiv = document.getElementById('selectionContainer');
        theDiv.appendChild(sourceImage);

    // Remove click event after clicking once

    $('.gameCover').off('click');   
    // Creating and appending the text from object.
    var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
        textDiv.className = 'textDiv';  

    // How to select object of image clicked????????????

 textDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(callOfDuty.showGame()));
    document.body.appendChild(textDiv);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this.src` or `$(this).prop('src')`

```
//How can you select the image that is clicked?
        // This.img????????????? 
        sourceImage.src = this.src;
```

You can modify the code in optimised way. Do not create images and text elements every time. Instead of this add `image` and text `div` in the html code and just change their contents on click of images. See below html and jquery.

HTML:

```
<div id = 'selectionContainer'> 
    <img src="" class="gameCoverFocus"></img>
</div>

<div id="text"></div>
```

jQuery: You need not to call `.off("click")` when you click on images. You can make use of `.one("click")` which will ensure that each image get click only once.

```
$('.gameCover').one("click",function() {
   $('#selectionContainer img').prop('src',this.src);
     $('#text').html(document.createTextNode(callOfDuty.showGame()));  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/km25vo7m/11/)**

Comment: +1, though I recommend `prop` for the jQuery solution

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your answer really helped me understand everything a lot better. So grateful!!  The only question i have is how do i get the written information to change as well??

Comment: you can create a map with key as image id and value as textnode object and set it as per clicked image id. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/km25vo7m/14/)

Comment: Another question, thought i'd ask here instead of creating a new question. How do i add a line break in my return code??